# NodeJS and Socket.io - Need to send video to all clients simultaneously

Tags: node.js, video, socket.io

I've set up a basic node server that listens for a button clicked on an Arduino (through socket.io). When the button is clicked, I emit 'goLoop' and the clients listen for it and then change the source of the video (through videojs).

The problem I'm having is that although it works, the videos are not completely in sync.  They are a split second off on all of the clients.

I thought that socket.io was asynchronous and that they would all emit the message for the videos to reset in parallel, but it seems like this is not the case.  I'm a noob, so I may not be doing this correctly.

Should socket.io send (emit) to all clients at the exact same time?  I really need all videos on the client end to be in sync.

Also part 2 to this question is, videojs doesn't seem to clear cache when changing the src dynamically.  It still seems to keep some reference of the previous video in memory.  How to I make sure that videojs completely clears its cache out after switching src.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide something reproducable. Are you emitting to a channel I guess?

Comment: Regarding sync, what are your requirements?  Even if socket.io emitted in perfect parallel (which I doubt it does) you would still have to take into account the latency of every individual connection and somehow add a delay to the faster connections.  If you've ever been in a room where a bunch of people are streaming the same Ustream feed you'll see they're not in sync either.

Comment: This is an impossible to solve problem. You will never be able to keep multiple clients in sync.